# Should programs check for failure on WinAPI functions that "shouldn't", but can, fail?

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

Recently I was updating some code used to take screenshots using the GetWindowDC -> CreateCompatibleDC -> CreateCompatibleBitmap -> SelectObject -> BitBlt -> GetDIBits series of WinAPI functions. Now I check all those for failure because they can and sometimes do fail. But then I have to perform cleanup by deleting the created bitmap, deleting the created dc, and releasing the window dc. In any example I've seen -- even on MSDN -- the related functions (DeleteObject, DeleteDC< ReleaseDC) aren't checked for failure, presumably because if they were retrieved/created OK, they will always be deleted/released OK. But, they still *can* fail.

That's just one noteable example since the calls are all right next to each other. But occasionally there are other functions that *can* fail but in practice never do. Such as GetCursorPos. Or functions that can fail only if passed invalid data, such as FileTimeToSytemTime.

So, is it good-practice to check ALL functions that can fail for failure? Or are some OK not to check? And as a corollary, when checking these should-never-fail functions for failure, what is proper? Throwing a runtime exception, using an assert, something else?

Comment: MSDN examples often seem to try to make things seem easy rather than showing robust error handling: I wouldn't use them as a benchmark of professionalism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You never know when a promised service will surprise by not working.  Best to report an error even for the surprises.  Otherwise you will find yourself with a customer saying your application doesn't work, and the reason will be a complete mystery; you won't be able to respond in a timely, useful way to your customer and you both lose.

If you organize your code to always do such checks, it isn't that hard to add the next check to that next API you call.

Comment: I agree it's not difficult and I do have these checks in place, but I have a nagging feeling that since I know, for example, that the DeleteDC function pre-conditions (passing a valid, created DC) will ensure success, that I'm writing code that will never be called. Like doing error checking to ensure the sin function returned a value between -1 and +1.

Comment: If you trust your function to always return a value between -1 and +1, you don't have to check.  Do you trust a Microsoft API (fronting 50 million lines) to always return a non-error result?

Comment: For ReleaseDC? To be honest, yes, I do. Well, I did anyway. I do see your point and agree with it. Perhaps I should put less stock in the fact that MSDN didn't use failure-checks for these functions, considering who wrote them...

Answer (score 5):

The question whether to test or not depends on what you would do if it failed. Most samples exit once cleanup is finished, so verifying proper clean up serves no purpose, the program is exiting in either case.

Not checking something like `GetCursorPos` could lead to bugs, but depending on the code required to avoid this determines whether you should check or not. If checking it would add 3 lines around all your calls then you are likely better off to take the risk. However if you have a macro setup to handle it then it wouldn't hurt to add that macro just in case.

`FileTimeToSystemTime` being checked depends on what you are passing into it. A file time from the system? probably safe to ignore it. A custom string built from user input? probably better to make sure.

Comment: A file time from the system? Wait till somebody types in "LPT:" as a file name into your program.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: You are using a conversion utility to verify input rather then checking the return value of the function that originally gave you the input?

Comment: I agree with this; it depends on what you are doing.  For instance, what do you do if fclose() fails?  Certain functions like that can't really return any meaningful error code, so their return values tend to be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

It's funny that you mention GetCursorPos since that fails on Wow64 processes when the address passed is >2Gb. It fails every time. The bug was fixed in Windows 7.

So, yes, I think it's wise to check for errors even when you don't expect them.

Comment: Hah! Well you got me there. GetCursorPos just jumped into my head; I'm sure there were better choices for unlikely-to-fail functions. Yet, as you said, clearly a solid reason in the 'Always Check' column...

Comment: There are other situations in which that function can fail too. I've also in the past assumed that it could not fail and been caught out. Even Microsoft's html help viewer falls foul of the bug I mention!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to check, but if you're using C++ you can take advantage of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and leave cleanup to the various resources that you are using.

The alternative would be to have a jumble of if-else statements, and that's really ugly and error-prone.

Comment: I am familiar with this if-else jumble you speak of. But RAII seems unnatural to me in this case. So in my first example, write a wrapper class around each WinAPI item? A BorrowedDC class that handles getting/releasing DCs, a CreatedDC class, a CreatedObject class?

Comment: Unfortunately for your particular objects you need to create a lot of wrappers. But for me the effort is worth it. After I'm done with it, I can read the logic without being tied up in figuring out the control flow of the error handling stuff.

Comment: At first I was hesitant, but considering the fact that this screen-capturing is one of the most critical sections of my program, it's definitely worth some extra classes for robustness. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Suppose you don't check what a function returned and the program just continues after the function failure. What happens next? How will you know why your program misbehaves long time later?

One quite reliable solution is to throw an exception, but this will require your code to be exception-safe.

Comment: Implementing exception-throwing is what made me want to write this question. If DeleteObject fails, before throwing the exception, I should still nest calls to DeleteDC and ReleaseDC. And if that nested DeleteDC fails, before throwing an exception, I still should nest a call to ReleaseDC. I started to think it was a lot of code for something that'll never run.

Comment: @rotanimod: You solve this problem by using RAII - just wrap creation/acquisition operations into a class that will do a corresponding releasing operation in its destructor. This will save you a lot of cleanup code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If a function *can* fail, then you *should* protect against it.

One helpful way to categorise potential problems in code  is by the potential causes of failure:

1. invalid operations in your code
2. invalid operations in client code (code that call yours, written by
   someone else)
3. external dependencies (file system, network connection etc.)

In situation 1, it is enough to detect the error and not perform recovery, as this is a bug that should be fixable by you.

In situation 2, the error should be notified to client code (e.g. by throwing an exception).

In situation 3, your code should recover as far as possible automatically, and notify any client code if necessary.

In both situations 2 & 3, you should endeavour to make sure that your code recovers to a valid state, e.g. you should try to offer ["strong exception guarentee"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_guarantees) etc.

Answer (score 1):

The longer I've coded with WinAPIs with C++ and to a lesser extent PInvoke and C#, the more I've gone about it this way:

1. Design the usage to assume it will fail (eventually) regardless of what the documentation seems to imply
2. Make sure to know the return value indication for pass/fail, as sometimes 0 means pass, and vice-versa
3. Check to see if `GetLastError` is noted, and decide what value that info can give your app

If robustness is a serious enough goal, you may consider it a worthy time-investment to see if you can do a somewhat fault-tolerant design with redundant means to get whatever it is you need. Many times with WinAPIs there's more than one way to get to the specific info or functionality you're looking for, and sometimes that means using other Windows libraries/frameworks that work in-conjunction with the WinAPIs.

For example, getting screen data can be done with straight WinAPIs, but a popular alternative is to use GDI+, which plays well with WinAPIs.